# Find the closest point from list to one referent list

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I have list of pairs of int coordinates like

```
list<pair<int,int> > coordinates;
```

I need to find the closest point to one Point origin,

```
class Point{
public:
float x;
float y;
};
```

I can find with custom comparator object and sorting but I am wondering is there quicker way with min ? I tried

```
class DistanceComparator{
public:
    DistanceComparator(const Point& p){origin=p;}
    inline bool operator<(std::pair<int,int> & lhs,std::pair<int,int > & rhs)
    {
        float deltaX1=lhs.first-origin.x;
        float deltaY1=lhs.second-origin.y;
        float deltaX2=rhs.first-origin.x;
        float deltaY2=rhs.second-origin.y;
        return (deltaX1*deltaX1+deltaY1*deltaY1)<(deltaX2*deltaX2+deltaY2*deltaY2);
    }
private:
    Pointorigin;
};
```

but < needs to take only one argument. How to do this ?

Answer (score 5):

Your solution is sub-optimal because it requires sorting the whole list, which isn't needed. You only need the minimum element, there's no need to sort the rest. Might I suggest you look into `std::partial_sort` or just go commando and iterate through it (`O(n)` as opposed to `O(n*log(n))` sorting).

Comment: Also std::nth_element (linear complexity avg)

Answer (score 2):

As Luchian Grigore already said, you shouldn't sort the list of points. However, I want to address your syntactical problem here.

You can't have a comparison operator as a class *member* which compares two *other* objects. You only have two possibilities to define a comparison operator:

1. A member function `bool T::operator<(const U& rhs) const` with `this` being the left hand side operand. (The const-reference is optional, I think, but highly recommended of course.) Note that `T == U` doesn't have to be true.
2. A non-member function `bool operator<(const T& lhs, const U& lhs) const` again with `T == U` not necessarily to be true.

So you **can't** have a comparison operator which has access to three objects as you want to have: the two operands and somewhat like a "context" which can **parametrize** the comparison.

To solve the problem I know the following two solutions (there might be more than that):

1. Set the additional parameter as a **global variable** when starting to use the comparison operator. Of course, this is very dirty (globals are always dirty in OOP) and makes the sorting non-reentrant. Since it is way too dirty I would never recommend it (but it still is a *possible* solution), thus I won't give an example code here.
2. Use a **predicate** instead of an `operator <`. There are multiple ways to do so. Here are two:

   *If you have c++0x / c++11 available:* Use a *lambda function* which can capture the additional parameter from the client context (where you run `std::sort`):

   ```
   Point origin = ...;
   std::sort(..., [origin](const Point & a, const Point & b){
       return distance(a, origin) < distance(b, origin);
   });
   ```

   *If you don't have c++0x / c++11 available:* You can still define a custom predicate to compare the two objects in a customized way without lambda functions. You have to define a comparator helper class:

   ```
   // Helper class:
   struct PointDistanceComparator {
       PointDistanceComparator(Point origin) : origin(origin) {}
       bool operator() (const Point & a, const Point & b) const {
           return distance(a, origin) < distance(b, origin);
       }
   private:
       Point origin;
   };

   // Client code:
   Point origin = ...;
   std::sort(..., PointDistanceComparator(origin));
   ```

   Of course you can (like you did) optimize the code to not use a square root for the calculation of the distance. The example code should only give you an idea on how to parametrize a comparison in general.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to query the list of coordinates many times you might want to consider using a **Kd-tree** for nearest neighbor search. This will have **O(log n)** time complexity.
Building and querying a Kd-tree is about 15-20 lines of (readable) C++ code. 
Have a look at the [Kd-tree wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)
Also have a look at `std::nth_element` , you can use this to efficiently build your Kd-tree (to choose the pivot point and partition the container (left and right childeren, see python code in wikipedia article).

**Update**: I create a [C++ N-dimensional K-d tree implementation](https://github.com/gvd/kdtree) with K-nearest neighbor search. It includes some unit tests that show you how to use it.

Comment: +1 for geometric data structure! Alternatively a [QuadTree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). :)